# Tilda zeroblock галерея-слайдер не отображает первое изображение, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tilda

Сделан pop-up в zeroblock, в блоке есть галерея-слайдер. При открытие popup галерея есть, но первое изображение не отображается если нажимаешь на кнопку слайдера или изменяешь размер окна браузера, то изображение появляется.

Цитата

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var Content = '#rec555753100'; //id Zero block
      var Wrapper = '#rec555985001'; //id блока popup окна BF503
      $(Wrapper + " .t-popup__container").html($(Content)).parent(".t-popup");
      $(Wrapper).addClass('ZeroInPopUp');
    });
  };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отключить lazy load для изображений в отдельном блоке или на всем сайте. Вот здесь инструкция https://lifehackov.ru/tilda-publishing/kak-otkljuchit-lazy-load-v-tilda/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)